# When getting cell content using Apache-POI Library, I get both "Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell" and the reverse of that. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx, illegalstateexception

I realize the question is a little confusing, but I didn't know how else to word it. Anyway, here is the original code:

```
private void readFile(String excelFileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(excelFileName));
    if (workbook.getNumberOfSheets() > 1){
        System.out.println("Please make sure there is only one sheet in the excel workbook.");
    }
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    int numOfPhysRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    XSSFRow row;
    XSSFCell num;
    for(int y = 1;y < numOfPhysRows;y++){    //start at the 2nd row since 1st should be category names
        row = sheet.getRow(y);
        poNum = row.getCell(1);
        item = new Item(Integer.parseInt(poNum.getStringCellValue());
        itemList.add(item);
        y++;
    }
}

private int poiConvertFromStringtoInt(XSSFCell cell){
    int x = Integer.parseInt(Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
    return x;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:781)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(XSSFCell.java:199)
```

Even if I change it to get either a string using `XSSFCell.getStringCellValue()` or even `XFFSCell.getRichTextValue`, I get the reverse of the above error message (and I am making sure to ultimately make it an int using `Integer.parseInt(XSSFCell.getStringCellValue()`).

The error then reads:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:781)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(XSSFCell.java:199)
```

I know for a fact that the excel spreadsheet column is in fact a string. I can't change the excel sheet as it is uploaded else where always using the same format and formatting each column first takes up to much processing time.

Any suggestions?

[Solution] Here is the solution code I came up with from @Wivani's help:

```
private long poiGetCellValue(XSSFCell cell){
    long x;
    if(cell.getCellType() == 0)
        x = (long)cell.getNumericCellValue();
    else if(cell.getCellType() == 1)
        x = Long.parseLong(cell.getStringCellValue());
    else
        x = -1;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Check the API; there are methods to query the type of a column, so you can use that to check if you have to convert or not. PS That code snippet is way insufficient to really help you debug.

Comment: To let everyone know what happened, I found out that the first 100 or so numbers had a leading 0. This caused excel to automatically make this a string. So I had to write a method to check the type first and then format accordingly. Thank you @Wivani

Comment: Interesting perhaps for future reference to add your 'solution code'?

Answer (score 53):

```
Use This as reference

switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                        System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                    System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks but the cases should be `XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_...`

Comment: @Mayank  Add a cast on System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue()); to get integer value because the avove statement returns a double. So correct answer for interger value is System.out.println((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());

Comment: @Mayank Convert RichStringCellValue to normal string by using toString() to get a string value which can be stored inside a string variable. So answer would be System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().toString());

Answer (score 26):

You can get value as String using the format defined for this cell :

```
final DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
final XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellIndex);
String valueAsString = df.formatCellValue(cell);
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18239468/894063).

Answer (score 21):

Just use cell.setCellType(1); before reading cell value and get it as String always, after that you can use it in your own format(type).

Ravi

Comment: This is not recommended, as it'll loose all the cell formatting information

Comment: I 'think' that doing this could cause it to not give back date fields quite the way you might want them... something to keep in mind if that's an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use the below code to read any data type from xcels using poi.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/**
 *
 * @author nirmal
 */
public class ReadWriteExcel {

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        ReadWriteExcel rw = new ReadWriteExcel();
        rw.readDataFromExcel();

    }
    Object[][] data = null;

    public File getFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File here = new File("test/com/javaant/ssg/tests/test/data.xlsx");
        return new File(here.getAbsolutePath());

    }

    public Object[][] readDataFromExcel() {
        final DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
        try {

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(getFile());
            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            int rownum = 0;
            int colnum = 0;
            Row r=rowIterator.next();

            int rowcount=sheet.getLastRowNum();
            int colcount=r.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            data = new Object[rowcount][colcount];
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                colnum = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                    data[rownum][colnum] =  df.formatCellValue(cell);
                    System.out.print(df.formatCellValue(cell));
                    colnum++;
                    System.out.println("-");
                }
                rownum++;
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got also this bug with POI version 3.12final.
I think that the bug is registered there : https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56702 and I put a comment there with my analysis.

Here is the workaround I used : The exception was risen by HSSFCell.getNumericCellValue which was called by DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted. DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted does 2 things :
1) check the value type of the cell by calling HSSFCell.getNumericCellValue and then DateUtil.isValidExcelDate(), which is almost pointless here I think.
2) check if the format of the cell is a date format

I copied the code of topic 2) above in a new function 'myIsADateFormat' and used it instead of DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted (that is quite dirty to copy library code, but it works...) :

```
private boolean myIsADateFormat(Cell cell){
    CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
    if(style == null) return false;
    int formatNo = style.getDataFormat();
    String formatString = style.getDataFormatString();
    boolean result = DateUtil.isADateFormat(formatNo, formatString);
    return result;
}
```

If you need to check the value type first, you can use this too :

```
CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
int cellValueType = cellValue.getCellType();
if(cellValueType == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
    if(myIsADateFormat(cell){
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation clearly says not to setCellType to 1 instead use the DataFormatter like how Thierry has explained:

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType(int)

Answer (score 0):

Ravi's solution works : 
Just use cell.setCellType(1); before reading cell value and get it as String always, after that you can use it in your own format(type).