# Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to match all formulas from my `ArrayList<String> cellListofFormula` to my sheet and to get the cell content out of this specified cells. Basically my celllistofFormula contains the cells like that `B1; B43; D66 etc.`

However, when iterating over my sheet with:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cellListofFormula.size(); i++) {

        CellReference ref = new CellReference(cellListofFormula.get(i).toString());
        Row r = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
        if (r != null) {
            Cell c = r.getCell(ref.getCol());
            FormulaEvaluator eval = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            eval.evaluateInCell(c);
            String value = c.getStringCellValue(); // I am getting the exception here
            System.out.println(c.getStringCellValue());
        }
    }
```

The exception I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.typeMismatch(HSSFCell.java:648)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.getRichStringCellValue(HSSFCell.java:725)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.getStringCellValue(HSSFCell.java:708)
    at com.excelParser.service.ExcelParser.readExcelData(ExcelParser.java:63)
    at com.excelParser.service.ExcelParser.main(ExcelParser.java:118)
```

The problem is that some cell values are numeric and some are string and some have formulas inside which give either a formula or a string value back. I just want to have the `String` value of the cell.

I appreciate your reply!

Comment: May be [This helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508203/when-getting-cell-content-using-apache-poi-library-i-get-both-cannot-get-a-num)

Comment: Use the `HSSFCell#getCellType()` method to determine what type of data the cell contains and then call the appropriate method(s) to get the value.  This is clearly spelled out in the API Javadocs.