# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have written code as below to fetch value from Excel.

```
String CID = s1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
```

but in excel, 1st cell is a numeric value, but in above code I am trying to fetch String cell value. thats why I am getting error as :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell
```

Can anyone please provide a solution for this. how to fetch the numeric value from excel?

Comment: That has nothing to do with Selenium.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When getting cell content using Apache-POI Library, I get both "Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell" and the reverse of that. How do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508203/when-getting-cell-content-using-apache-poi-library-i-get-both-cannot-get-a-num)

Answer (score 4):

getCellType() for any cell gives you the type of the cell.The types are:

```
Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK
Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC
Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING
Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA
Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN
Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR
```

It is better to use a switch statement and collect the correct type of cell value.
There exists getNumericCellValue() and getStringCellValue() functions but it is safer with types.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think that exists `getNumericalCellValue()` or `getIntegerCellValue()` which returns what you want.

Comment: the mentioned command is there, but after fetching this value, i need to pass it as an argument to sendkeys() which accepts only string

Comment: You can always use something like `String cell = Integer.toString(numericCell)` or `String cell = String.valueOf(numericCell)`

Answer (score 0):

Add apostrophe as prefix to that number in cell, automatically it will be converted as text. it had worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Check the cell type first and then get its value.

```
           row.getCell(index).getCellType();
Number ==> row.getCell(index).getNumericCellValue();
String ==> row.getCell(index).getStringCellValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use it =>

```
String CID = new BigDecimal(s1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue()).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

String unitPrice = new Float(wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(7).getNumericCellValue()).toString();

Note: its the best way to get the data in string if the value is stored in the numerical type in excel file.
where we are getting the data from 7th cell of 1st row.

Answer (score 0):

```
final DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
final XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellIndex);
String valueAsString = df.formatCellValue(cell);
```

This might help

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me

```
package dummy;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class read_excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filename = "abP.xlsx";

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            //XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();

                    CellType type = cell.getCellTypeEnum();
                    if (type == CellType.STRING) {
                        System.out.println("[" + cell.getRowIndex() + ", "
                            + cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = STRING; Value = "
                            + cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
                    } else if (type == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        System.out.println("[" + cell.getRowIndex() + ", "
                                     + cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = NUMERIC; Value = "
                                      + cell.getRawValue());
                        
                      //  System.out.println("[" + cell.getRowIndex() + ", "
                      //      + cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = NUMERIC; Value = "
                       //     + cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else if (type == CellType.BOOLEAN) {
                        System.out.println("[" + cell.getRowIndex() + ", "
                            + cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = BOOLEAN; Value = "
                            + cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    } else if (type == CellType.BLANK) {
                        System.out.println("[" + cell.getRowIndex() + ", "
                            + cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = BLANK CELL");
                    }
                    else if (type == CellType.FORMULA) {
                        System.out.println("[" + cell.getRowIndex() + ", "
                            + cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = BLANK CELL");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please add an apostrophe before number in Excel cell. That solved my similar problem when using Revit API. E.g:

'123